# Image fits into UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using `collectionview` to display the products where I fetched from the server. However images does not fit into the `collectionview` cell. I wonder is there a way of fixing it?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myURL/productAll.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSError *myError = nil;
    id res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];        
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[res count]; i++) {
        NSString *arrayResult = [[res objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"image"];            
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:arrayResult options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
        UIImage *captcha_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [items addObject:captcha_image];
    }
    [collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

Here is the `collectionView` cell design, `imageView` dimension matches with `collectionView` cell.
[image]

Here is what user sees:

[image]

Here are the extra information from ImageView

[image]

[image]

cellCollectionView

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pinning the UIImageView to the superview borders and setting contentMode as aspectToFill?

Comment: I have added more setting information (screenshots)

Comment: try by using autolayout constraint. give all four side for image or even you can try it by auto re-sizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, modern Apple devices get various sizes. It's not 2010 anymore when you design only for one screen. Move to Autolayout.
Secondly, below you can find a very detailed explanation of how to do all the proper Setup.

1. Click on your image view
2. Click on the pin constraints button
3. Put down the constants(same as margins) and select/highlight the red connectors box-to-numbers
4. Uncheck "Constraints to margins" checkbox
5. Click add 4 constraints button
6. Be Sure your image view mode is Aspect Fill
7. Don't forget to check important "Clip subviews" checkbox, unless you will see enlarged images over each other

[image: Detailed explanation for adding constants]

[image: Detailed explanation for Image View setup]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use frames, ever.

It's 2015, use autolayout.

Create your classic custom cell, put an imageview there and put it's top, left, right and bottom constraints to the edge of the actual cell.

Don't forget to link your outlet imageview to your .h file and set it's image when creating the cell.

Boom, you're good to go, your image will always fill the space of the cell.

You'll probably need to set clip subviews to true on your cell if you have rounded corners.

Thought in your case, just showing an imageview in the cell should be fine without constraints if your cell has the exact same size as your imageview in your protocell, and of course that your imageview takes the whole protocell.

Comment: could you please give an example of how to make setclipsubview to true?

Comment: By the way, I have made it autolayout, it works but even if I increase the collectionView dimension from 100 to 150 and also image as well and redo theautolayout, it still keeps the same dimension, no changes.

Comment: In storyboard, it's a checkbox at the bottom ;)
If your view A has Clip Subviews to true (checked), then ALL the views inside (under) the view A will not exceed its bounds. A clear example is if view A has rounded corners, the  views inside will not show as squares and "go further" than the corners. The view **clips** everything that goes beyond its limits

Comment: @Zil I think that this answer is too general and doesn't solve the specific problem.

Comment: I respectfully disagree